# How to use TipTap insertContent for bulletlist

Tags: javascript, tiptap, prose-mirror

TipTap v2 docs for insertContent has an example for inserting a paragraph node.

```
editor.commands.insertContent([
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    content: [
      {
        type: 'text',
        text: 'First paragraph',
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

What's the object format for inserting a bulletlist or how does one figure out the object structure?

```
editor.commands.insertContent({
          type: 'bulletList',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'listItem',
              content: 'some string,
            },
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for bulletlist

```
editor.commands.insertContent({
  type: 'bulletList',
  content: [
    {
      type: 'listItem',
      content: [
        {
          type: 'paragraph',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text',
              text: 'first bullet',
            },
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'listItem',
      content: [
        {
          type: 'paragraph',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text',
              text: '2nd bullet',
            },
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Why this Object structure?

bulletList is composed of [listItems](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/extension-bullet-list/src/bullet-list.ts#L31)

listItem comes from the [extension source code](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/extension-bullet-list/src/bullet-list.ts#L40)

listItem is composed of [content: 'paragraph block*'](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/extension-list-item/src/list-item.ts#L16): means 0 or more paragraph blocks

paragraph is composed of [content: 'inline*'](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/extension-paragraph/src/paragraph.ts#L31): means 0 or more inline blocks

inline is composed of [text](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/extension-text/src/text.ts) or other inline nodes

Thus you get the above data structure.